# Properties of Natural Logarithm I need help finding the Derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

$y=\ln(x)^2$

I am not sure why the answer would be $\frac{2\ln(x)}{x}$

I used this property "power rule" "$\ln(x^n) = n\ln(x)$

So i got $2\ln(x) $

the derivative of that using the constant multiplier rule i got

$\frac{2}{x}$

can I use the other chain rule to $y=f(u)$ and $g=g(x)$
Am i not supposed to bring that 2 in front becuase the whole expression is getting raised not the $x$?
Any help would be great,

Comment: Look at the parentheses, $(\log x)^2 \neq \log (x^2)$.

Comment: Careful: $$\log(x^n)=n\log x\neq (\log x)^n=\log^nx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the chain rule with $\;f(x):=x^2\;,\;\;g(x):=\log x$ :

$$(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$

So

$$(\log x)^2=2\log x\cdot \frac1x=\frac{2\log x}x$$

Comment: So another way of looking at the chain rule is using the power rule  multipilying the derivative of the inside function? i think that works? am i right?

Comment: Well...yes, that's what I wrote, if I understood your comment correctly.

Comment: Yes the chain rule composition formula is confusing for me to look at thank you for the help

Comment: John, if you accept somebody's answer, please give him an upvote. Particularly if the answer is correct.